# to Call subclasses that have same variable and value

Tags: ios, swift

so I have Animal superclass and three subclass : lion dog and elephant.

```
enum Gender {
    case male
    case female
}

class Animal {
    var species: String
    var gender: Gender

    init (species: String, gender: Gender) {
        self.species = species
        self.gender = gender
    }
}

// Lion Class    
class Lion: Animal {
    var age: Int = 10

    init () {
        super.init(species: "Lion", gender: Gender.male)
    }
}

// Elephant Class
class Elephant: Animal {    
    var age: Int = 8

    init () {
        super.init(species: "Elephant", gender: Gender.female)
    }
}

//Dog Class
class Dog: Animal {
    var age: Int = 6

    init () {
        super.init(species: "Dog", gender: Gender.female)
    }
}
```

They all have gender variable which is inherited from superclass Animal.
Now I want to have a computed property: `maleAnimal` of type `[Animal]` which contains all male animal, what is the best way to do it ?

```
class Zoo {
    var animals: [Animal] = [Lion(), Elephant(), Dog()]

    var maleAnimals: [Animal] {
        for animalClasses in animals {
            if animalClasses.gender == Gender.male {
               return self.maleAnimals.append(animalClasses)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried some thing like the example beneath but it apparently does not work.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: filter does exactly what you need: it filter out what doesn't fit your condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `filter` method on arrays.

```
var maleAnimals : [Animal] {
    return animals.filter { $0.gender == .male }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the first male animal that you find. You should use the 'filter' method on the 'animals' array.

```
var maleAnimals: [Animal] {
    return animals.filter { $0.gender == .male }
}
```

Comment: Seems I was slower ;) See the answer from @Yannick

Answer (score 2):

While other answers is correct and thats how you should use, here is the fix for your code, basically you have to create new variable inside the closure, assign value to it, then return it, hope it can give u a bit more understanding of how to use computed value

```
var maleAnimals : [Animal] {
        var array = [Animal]()
        for animalClasses in animals {
            if animalClasses.gender == Gender.male {
                array.append(animalClasses)
            }
        }
        return array
    }
```